# Error parsing query in SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, sql, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

I have an existing application running on Windows Mobile running SQL Server CE and am using inline queries with C# language. This is my query that works correctly in Management Studio:

```
command = @"SELECT  
                P_InspectionStep.InspectionStepID,
                P_InspectionStep.Sequence AS Sequence,
                P_InspectionStep.Title AS Title,
                P_InspectionStep.Body AS Body,
                P_InspectionStep.Photo AS Photo,
                P_Inspection.RevisionID
            FROM
                P_InspectionStep
            LEFT JOIN 
                P_Inspection ON P_Inspection.InspectionID = P_InspectionStep.InspectionID
            WHERE 
                P_Inspection.InspectionID = '" + mInspectionID + "'" +
                @"AND P_Inspection.CreateDate = (SELECT MAX(P_Inspection.CreateDate) FROM P_Inspection)

            UNION ALL

            SELECT
                C_InspectionStep.InspectionStepID,
                C_InspectionStep.Sequence AS Sequence,
                C_InspectionStep.Title AS Title,
                C_InspectionStep.Body AS Body,
                C_InspectionStep.Photo AS Photo,
                C_Inspection.RevisionID
            FROM 
                C_InspectionStep
            LEFT JOIN 
                C_Inspection ON C_Inspection.RevisionID = C_InspectionStep.RevisionID
            WHERE 
                C_Inspection.InspectionID = '" + mInspectionID + "'" +
                @"AND C_Inspection.CreateDate = (SELECT MAX(C_Inspection.CreateDate) FROM C_Inspection)
            ORDER BY 2;";
```

But running it in the application returns this `SqlCeException`:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 10,Token line offset = 132,Token in error = SELECT ]

I've done a lot of searching but can't find out how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the value of

```
(SELECT MAX(P_Inspection.CreateDate) FROM P_Inspection)
```

from another query run in advance.

Comment: This solution also causes the native exception I described under @Alex K. solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a sub-query that returns a scalar value but you can return a set so use `IN` instead of an equality test:

```
... C_Inspection.CreateDate IN (SELECT MAX(C_Inspection.CreateDate) FROM C_Inspection)
```

Comment: I tried this and I get a native exception in the application exe that I can't catch with the debugger.  Looks like something with the reader Move direction.  I copied the command value into a sql query window and it returns data fine.